# How can I print text with spaces from array?

Tags: php, arrays

In this array I have user with her ID:

```
$data = array( 'USER : Alex K. id:1', 'USER : Robert K. id:2');
```

The name on the id 1 is "Alex K." and on the id 2 is

```
foreach ( $data as $string )
{
    $_a = explode( ':', $string );
    $_b = explode( ' ', $_a[1] );
    $inf[$_a[2]] = $_b[1];
}
```

If i use `print_r( $inf[ID] );` for example `print_r( $inf[2] );` this show me only "Robert" but no "Robert K.";

I try with `print_r( $_b );` and I get all data buy I donw know how print the complete name.

Someone know how do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of the array's members is always the same, you can simply grab specific parts of the string, eg. using `preg_match`:

```
foreach ($data as $string) {
    preg_match('/USER : (?<name>.*?) id:(?<id>\d+)/', $string, $match);

    printf('User: %s. His ID: %d', $match['name'], $match['id']);
}
```

Otherwise you have to "clean" the input string before exploding it by a "space" – by removing the noise, things you don't need, like the `USER :` part (functions which may come in handy: `str_replace` / `substr` etc.)

If you need to somehow manipulate this list, you would have to index it first, eg. by the `id`:

```
$users = [];

foreach ($data as $string) {
    preg_match('/USER : (?<name>.*?) id:(?<id>\d+)/', $string, $match);

    $users[$match['id']] = $match['name'];
}

printf('User name with ID 1 is: %s', $users[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I filtre ir with a ID?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "filter"

Comment: For example If I want show the name of the user with the id number 2, how can I do it with your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on performing any other searches on the input array, then you don't need to generate a new, re-structured, associative lookup array.

[preg_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) will find your user by id and isolate the user name in one step.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DXlCN)) (or [if users may have colons in their names](https://3v4l.org/TmKTj))

```
$data = ['USER : Alex K. id:1', 'USER : Robert K. id:2'];
$id = 2;
var_export(current(preg_filter('/USER : ([^:]*) id:' . $id . '$/', '$1', $data)));
```

Output:

```
'Robert K.'
```

`preg_filter()` will iterate all of the elements and try to modify them, but since the `$id` variable at the end of the pattern will only allow one of the elements to be matched/modified, it will be the only element in the returned data.

`current()` will grab the first/only element if there is one.  If there is no match, then the output will be `false`.

I am using `var_export()` to show that there are no leading or trailing spaces -- you can use `echo` just the same.